# Override method parameter with child interface as a new parameter

Tags: php, oop

I cant figure out why this code does not work in PHP?

```
<?php

interface Engine {

    function run();
}

interface HydroEngine extends Engine {

    function run();
}

interface Car {

    function setEngine(Engine $engine);

}

interface WaterCar extends Car {

    function setEngine(HydroEngine $engine);
}

?>
```

It seems it does not break any OOP rules, but why it gives me an error?

`Fatal error: Declaration of WaterCar::setEngine() must be compatible with Car::setEngine(Engine $engine)`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It *does* break [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) rules. You declare `Car::setEngine` to accept one parameter of type `Engine`, but the child `WaterCar::setEngine` accepts a parameter of type `HydroEngine`. Even if `HydroEngine` is a subtype of `Engine`, it's still a different type.

When a class `Foo implements WaterCar`, it is also true that this class is an `instanceof Car`. But `Foo::setEngine` accepts a `HydroEngine`, but does not accept an `Engine`. So `Foo::setEngine` supposedly `implements Car`, yet does not accept a parameter of type `Engine`. Which breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). You cannot change the type of parameters in subclassed interfaces, period.

The keyword for inheritance is explicitly *`extends`*. A subclass does *exactly the same* as the parent class and possibly *more*. It cannot do *less* than the parent. Since `HydroEngine` is a specialized subtype of `Engine`, this would mean a `WaterCar` does *less* than a `Car`, since it only accepts a more narrow subtype of `Engine`. E.g.:

```
function (Car $car) {
    $engine = new EngineImplementation;
    $car->setEngine($engine);
}
```

The above code would implode if you passed in a `WaterCar`, because it does not accept an `Engine`.

Comment: probably I misunderstood LSP before.. but I think Java allows you to make this thing (am I wrong?)

Comment: No idea. PHP doesn't. :) And I hope the explanation for why makes sense to you.

Comment: yes, thanks. I was thinking that `HydroEngine` does *exactly the same or more* then `Engine` - that is why its acceptable for lsp, but now your explanation does make sense

Comment: But consider an instance `$wc` that implements `WaterCar` and is passed to a function/method that expects something that implements `Engine`. It tests the object via `instanceof(Engine)` and then passes a `IonEngine` to the watercar instance ...boom. Eiffel is the only language I know of that allows covariant redefinitions.

Comment: @Volker Yup, that's a great feature. But PHP, and as you said most other languages, don't implement "accepts something of type x" but only "is type x".

Comment: @Pleerock Yes, `HydroEngine` does indeed the same and more as `Engine`, but an object which *accepts* `HydroEngine` yet not `Engine` does not. :)

Comment: But, will the `WaterCar` work if it is fitted with just any `Engine` instead of `HydroEngine`. because by definition it should accept it? What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the method signature still needs to be exactly the same because at compile time it doesn't work out if HydroEngine is an Engine.

```
interface WaterCar extends Car {
    function setEngine(Engine $engine);
}
```