# Why does PHP allow you to overload typehints on constructors but not on methods?

Tags: php

Suppose you have this:

```
<?php

interface Type
{}

class SomeType implements Type
{}

class SomeOtherType implements Type
{}
```

Now, if you had an abstract class that has the `Type` interface as a constructor dependency, like this:

```
<?php

abstract class TypeUser
{
        public function __construct(Type $type)
        {}
}
```

Why does PHP allows you to overload the constructor on the concrete classes like this:

```
<?php

class SomeTypeUser extends TypeUser
{
        public function __construct(SomeType $type)
        {}
}

class SomeOtherTypeUser extends TypeUser
{
        public function __construct(SomeOtherType $type)
        {}
}
```

But it doesn't allow you to do the same for methods, only constructors — if you try to do that with non-constructor methods, PHP throws a `Strict standards` error?

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me: http://ideone.com/PjFIa8

Comment: My guess is that it's because you are more likely to know the type during construction than during method invocation. The constructor overload behavior is still wrong, but its less likely to be a problem than overloading the parameter type of a method.

Comment: @Kasyx set the error_reporting(E_ALL) and check it out again.

Comment: @drgomesp same result... Which version of php are you using?

Comment: @Kasyx You need to update your php.ini for it, the warning is thrown at compile time, before `error_reporting()` calls are applied.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this: [Override method parameter with child interface as a new parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429089/override-method-parameter-with-child-interface-as-a-new-parameter/19429227#19429227)

TL;DR: If you overload a method parameter type with a *narrower* type, the method signature is changed and made *incompatible* with the parent method. You cannot substitute an instance of `TypeUser` with any arbitrary subclass, because the overloaded subclasses' method signatures are incompatible with the parent's and hence no stable, known interface for calling such an instance is given.

Why does it work on a constructor? Because to construct an instance, you (typically) hardcode its classname:

```
$user = new SomeTypeUser($parameter);
```

There's no ambiguity here what parameters the constructor expects, you know exactly what class you're instantiating.

However, that is not the case here:

```
function (TypeUser $user) {
    $user->foo($something);
}
```

Well, what class is `$user` an instance of? `SomeTypeUser`? `SomeOtherTypeUser`? Something entirely different? Is `$user->foo()`'s signature `foo(SomeType $type)` or `foo(SomeOtherType $type)`? Will the code above explode at runtime or not? Who knows...

Answer (score -1):

PHP does allow overloading parameters in inherted methods as long as they are not defined as `abstract` or belong to an `interface` which the class extends/implements.

```
interface Foo {
    public function baz(ArrayObject $array);
}

class Bar implements Foo {
   public function baz(DateTime $dateTime) {
   }
}
```

or

```
abstract class Foo {
    public abstract function baz(ArrayObject $array);
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   public function baz(DateTime $dateTime) {
   }
}
```

Will result int the well known error:

> Fatal error:  Declaration of Bar::baz() must be compatible with Foo::baz(ArrayObject $array) in /.../test.php on line xy

While

```
abstract class Foo {
    public function baz(ArrayObject $array) {
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   public function baz(DateTime $dateTime) {
   }
}
```

is fine and works because the `baz` method is not an implemention of an interface defined method nor it is an abstract method in a parent class.

Comment: I still have the error with your working example... It's not a fatal error, but a `PHP Strict standards:  Declaration of...` warning

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER to me: `PHP Strict standards:  Declaration of Bar::baz() should be compatible with Foo::baz(ArrayObject $array)` on 5.5.14

Comment: @drgomesp On 5.5.11 it works fine. We're talking about the 3rd (working) example right?

Comment: Right. This is really weird

Comment: Show me the exact code which lead to the error you posted 2 comments ago... I think we're mixing somehting up.

Comment: Okay very strange. This really works for me on 5.5.11.

Comment: Do you have strict errors enabled? Try error_reporting(E_ALL)

Comment: This doesnt make any sense. It should throw an error.

Comment: Why should it? Overloading is allowed for none abstract and none interface based methods. So this should not end up in an error. But I get for my first two examples the Declaration of Bar::baz() error.

Comment: Because the declaration is not compatible.

Comment: Well there's not declaration there's just an overloading of the method. It's not about implementing an interface method nor a abstract method just override a parent class method with a new one.