# Overloarding methods in php

Tags: php, abstract-class, parent-child, overloading

I have a problem in design my project code.

For example:

I have two model class: `AClass` and `BClass` which `extends` from `CClass` class. 
For each of this class I have two service layer: `AService` and `BService` in which I have methods:

`create(AClass $object)` and `create(BClass $object)` corresponding.

So what I want. I want create `Abstract Service CService` in which I have abstract class `create(CClass class)`. And my `AService` and `BService` must `extends` from`CService`. 
But in `PHP` I can't do this cause it failed for compatible exception.

So maybe some ideas how I can resolve this problem?

Update:
Maybe not very good example above, so I show you in real case:

```php
abstract class Contract
{
    protected $id;
    protected $owner
}

class FundTraderContract extends Contract
{
    private $fundContract;
}

class InvestorTraderContract extends Contract
{
    private $investmentContract;
}

abstract class ContractService 
{
    abstract function create(Contract $contract){}
}

class FundTraderContractService extends ContractService
{
    public function create(FundTraderContract $contract)
    {
        //some logic
    }
}


class InvestorTraderContractService extends ContractService
{
    public function create(InvestorTraderContract $contract)
    {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

I think now example more easy-to-see. So in this case there is a compatible problem.

Comment: I for one welcome our new method overloards. ;)

Comment: Just FYI, you're not the first one to ask this, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/19429089/476. Having two class hierarchies essentially going in parallel doesn't really work, not just in PHP. I'm curios for design solutions to this one.

Answer (score 4):

First off, apologies if this isn't **exactly** what you want - since you've stripped all the class names and just gone to AClass etc, it's really hard to actually understand the logic of your application.

---

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle

Create an interface. Without knowing your actual classes it's impossible to give it a meaningful name, but you do this:

```
interface DInterface {  }

class AClass implements DInterface {  }
class BClass implements DInterface {  }

class CClass
{
    public function something(DInterface $class) {  }
}
```

You can then define stuff inside `DInterface` that should be in both `AClass` and `BClass`, ie. if `CClass::something` expects to be able to call `$class->all()` then you can define `public function all();` in `DInterface`, and PHP will error out if either `AClass` or `BClass` doesn't implement it.

Comment: Might also want to make a comment on interface segregation

Comment: @Flosculus For what it's worth, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle, but it might be a bit much to take in in one go :)

Comment: @Joe So, if I define create(CClass $class) in DInterface, but in AClass i define create(AClass $class) I will have the same error. Or maybe I don't understand something?

Comment: @AndreyKhodan can you rewrite your OP to explain what you're trying to do in terms of "InvestorTraderContractService" etc, rather than AClass and BClass? It'll be much easier :)

Comment: @AndreyKhodan The example you are using breaks the contract (oop term) for `::create` both in OOP principles and in reality.  If the services are dependent on separate concrete instances, then they are fundamentally incompatible.  Its not necessarily a mistake on your part, its just this route may not work for you.  Unless you can find a way to make them dependent only on `Contract`.