# Type-hinted interface methods not accepting derivative types

Tags: php

It seems fairly straightforward to me that a hinted Type in PHP should include all derivatives of that type. However, I'm getting errors and I'm wondering if I'm either misunderstanding this or if I'm just doing it wrong. Here's my simple test case:

```
<?php

interface A { }
interface A1 extends A { } // A1 is a specific type of A

interface B {
    function test(A $a); // B::test requires an object of type A
}

class ConcreteB implements B {
    function test(A1 $a) {
        echo "cha";
    }
}

?>
```

This program obviously doesn't do anything, but it's sufficient to demonstrate the problem: When I "run" it, PHP throws up a `Fatal error:  Declaration of ConcreteB::test(A1 $a) must be compatible with B::test(A $a)`.

Theoretically, since `A1` is a type of `A`, the two declarations should be seen as compatible, since you would be able to call any `A` function on `A1` and thus polymorphism is preserved.

Any thoughts as to why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, i just realized that your interface calls for a different argument.

Please see

[Override method parameter with child interface as a new parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429089/override-method-parameter-with-child-interface-as-a-new-parameter)

for a most excellent answer.

Comment: Oof, of course. The reason this doesn't work can be more clearly explained: `ConcreteB` and `B` should remain interchangeable where dependencies are concerned. While this works going up (everything expecting `B` can work with `ConcreteB`) it doesn't work going down (not everything expecting `ConcreteB` will work with `B`).

I'm not totally sure this is actually ideal, but having clearly defined rules is valuable, so I suppose I can't complain.