# PHP - Standard class extends an Abstract class with dependency injection (only in the standard class)

Tags: php, dependency-injection, abstract-class

I'm having an issue and I'm wondering if I'm doing it the right way. For instance, here is my first class:

```
<?php
abstract class AbstractForm
{
   abstract function save($request, $database);
}
```

Then, in my second class, I'd like to extend that `AbstractForm` with this second class

```
<?php
class SalesForm extends AbstractForm
{
   function save($request, SalesDatabase $database);
}
```

I want to do this because I could have a different Form, that would follow the same rules but having another database, for instance

```
<?php
class HrForm extends AbstractForm
{
   function save($request, HrDatabase $database);
}
```

It seems to give me a Fatal Error since it says that my declaration doesn't follow the one told in `AbstractForm`. I'd like to know if there is a good way (or workaround) to make it work? Could I provide my `AbstractDatabase` in the `AbstractForm` as a dependency injection and then provide a child of this class? What exactly would be possible at this point?

Comment: Why must you redefine the accepted type in the subclass anyway? That's not type safe anymore. If a function type hints for `AbstractForm`, it cannot know what subclass it will receive and hence what type `save` will accept. That's the whole point why you define an interface or abstract class in the first place and then **stick to the declared types.**

Comment: @deceze I understand what you mean, but I feel like I should be able to, at least, provide that Form that extends abstract Form should be at least children of the database object, or something that extends it. I may have many different forms that will each need a database and the save function (for sure), but I'd like then to be able to say that it has to be different type of database depending on which type of form it is.

Comment: → http://stackoverflow.com/a/19429227/476