# types of methods with respect to types of methods in superclass in python

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, liskov-substitution-principle

I'm pretty new to Python's typing system, and I didn't find this description in the documentation I've reviewed until now.

If `Asub` is a subclass of `Bsup`, and `Asub` has a multi-argument method named `foo`.  What should I do and what should I avoid when annotating the type of the `foo` in `Asub`? For example, should I always assure that the return type in the subclass is *exactly* the same as that in the super class, or that the return type in the subclass is at least a superclass of that in the superclass?  And what about the arguments?   Should the arguments of the method in the subclass always be the same type or rather a subtype of the arguments in the superclass?

Also, if (as is *usually* the case), do I need to declare types on the method in the subclass if the types are exactly the same as in the superclass?

```py
class Bsup:
  def foo(self, x: A) -> B:
     ...

class Asub (Bsup):
  def foo(self, x: X) -> Y:
    ...
```

Comment: Always consider the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). **Any subclass may be used at any place a super class may be used.** So the subclass must accept arguments which are the same *or higher* (superclasses) as the super class' method, and it must return values which are the same *or lower* (subclasses) as the super class' method. Here's something about the same topic, albeit in PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19429089/476

Comment: Is this mentioned in the typing documentation?   Why do I ask?  because some object systems DO NOT obey LSP and some do.  And some object systems even enforce LSP on parameterized types.

Comment: Python doesn't *enforce* any of this. Python explicitly has a duck typing philosophy; as long as it doesn't raise an error at runtime, it's fine. But to have a sound type system, you must follow the LSP.

Comment: I'm still new to Python typing myself. Having it only checked by mypy but not enforced yields strange situations sometimes. I'm glad you found your answer in the manual, thanks for sharing that link.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer in the mypy documentation.
[Overriding statically typed methods](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/class_basics.html#overriding-statically-typed-methods)

This documentation explains and gives examples of methods in derived classes returning more specific objects, and annotating the return value as such.  It also addresses some error cases, and hints at how mypy handles covariance and contravariance.   Thus my interpretation of the documentation gives some indication to which extent mypy implements LSP.

Comment: This answer risks being deleted as a "link-only answer". I suggest editing it to at least say that yes, mypy implements the LSP principle.

Comment: Note that this isn't the *Python* documentation, it's the mypy documentation, which is an external type checker which operates according to specific rules it thinks are good. And they *are* pretty sensible, but they're not the only rules which are *technically possible*. Python itself doesn't care as long as your code won't produce any runtime errors.