# Why is Python's type hint with Callable with base class as argument not compatible with parameter with child class

Tags: python, inheritance, type-hinting

I have the following two classes:

```py
class MessageBase:
    pass

class MessageChild(MessageBase):
    pass
```

And the following function:

```py
def action(message: MessageChild):
    pass
```

Why does the following type hint for the given `get_action` function produces an error in Pylance? Normally type hints using base classes are compatible with child classes.

```py
def get_action() -> Callable[[MessageBase], None]:
    return action
```

```
Expression of type "(message: MessageChild) -> None" cannot be assigned to return type "(MessageBase) -> None"
  Type "(message: MessageChild) -> None" cannot be assigned to type "(MessageBase) -> None"
    Parameter 1: type "MessageBase" cannot be assigned to type "MessageChild"
      "MessageBase" is incompatible with "MessageChild"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19429227/476 … If you promise to return something that accepts a `MessageBase`, but in fact only accepts a `MessageChild`, then you could not pass a `MessageBase` to this function, which would break the contract.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you flesh out your example a bit, you see why you get this warning:

```
class MessageChild(MessageBase):
    def method_only_child_has(self):
        pass


def action(message: MessageChild):
    message.method_only_child_has()
```

We've added something to `MessageChild` which does not exist in `MessageBase`. `action` expects a `MessageChild` and can thus rely on that special something to be there.

Now:

```
the_action = get_action()
the_action(MessageBase())
```

According to the type annotation on `get_action`, this is supposed to work. `the_action` supposedly expects an argument of type `MessageBase`, which we're providing here as requested. When you actually execute this code though, you'll get an `AttributeError`, since `method_only_child_has` does not in fact exist on `MessageBase`.

That's the type error it's warning you about. It's not about an insufficient type annotation, it's correctly warning you about an actual potential error case.

Comment: Now I got it. What is the most adequate type hint in my case then?

Comment: `action` should probably accept a `MessageBase`, but can then of course only rely on the interface defined by it.